# How to use require to import a custom icon with react leaflet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-draw

I have read several posts here on stackoverflow like [React Leaflet - How to render custom image using Circle Markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62743905/react-leaflet-how-to-render-custom-image-using-circle-markers)
and
[custom marker icon with react-leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47723812/custom-marker-icon-with-react-leaflet)
On how to include custom icons in react leaflet maps. I have tried the below code

```
const newicon = new L.icon({
      iconUrl: require('../assets/Download-Image.png'),
      iconSize: [30, 30]  
    })
```

but the image does not render on the map.

However, if I use the url of the same icon as below it works and renders. Any advise on what I could be doing wrong?

```
const newicon = new L.icon({
      iconUrl: 'https://www.somewebsite/Download-Image.png',
      iconSize: [30, 30]  
    })
```

Answer (score 4):

You should not place `require` between `''`: only the image path inside require.

```
const newicon = new L.icon({
  iconUrl: require("./assets/marker.png"),
  iconSize: [30, 30]
});

export default function App() {
  const position = [51.505, -0.09];

  return (
    <Map center={position} zoom={13} style={{ height: "500px" }}>
      <TileLayer
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      />
      <Marker position={position} icon={newicon}>
        <Popup>
          A pretty CSS3 popup.
          <br />
          Easily customizable.
        </Popup>
      </Marker>
    </Map>
  );
}
```

Another approach, which is mostly used would be to import the image like below:

```
import marker from "./assets/marker.png";
```

and then use it like this:

```
const newicon = new L.icon({
  iconUrl: marker,
  iconSize: [30, 30]
});
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-require-to-import-image-paths-on-react-leaflet-yzdfm)

Comment: Thanks @Kboul but `require` between the quotation marks was a typo on my post, I fixed it. Anyway I had tried your suggestions before, but still can't get the image to render in the map. I just get the no image available icon. Not sure if it's an issue with the package I have or not.

Comment: Did you try the 2nd approach?

Comment: I could help if you were able to provide a demo with your app.